# css shadows are fine with firefox and chrome but not showing on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

css shadows are fine with firefox and chrome but not showing on Internet Explorer 
I used following code

```
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
```

Can someone suggest me a solution for this

Thank You!

Comment: Although the solution is in the Answers, it is commonly-accepted wisdom that box shadows are "progressive enhancements" and that their absence shouldn't cause a negative experience for other users. In other words, it's a commonly-held belief (one I share) that using CSS3 box shadows is enough; there's no compelling need to fool around with filters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;` is only for FireFox.

You can use `box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;`

IE < 9 needs some help.  You need something like this

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=2,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.20);

-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=2,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.20)";
        zoom: 1;
```

You'll have to play with the values.

All together it could be

```
.something{
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=2,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.20);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=2,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.20)"; zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: won't this run `filter` for IE9+ as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about IE versions < 9, then you'll need to use a poly-fill like [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

Otherwise, be sure to use the non-vendor prefixed rule (no -moz or -webkit in front of the rule) after you've included the vendor -prefixed versions.

Comment: you do'nt need to use a poly-fill, you can use IE proprietary filter, -ms-filter

Comment: i disagree, filters are native to IE. poly fills more than likely use {filter} to correct in ie. polyfills are shims, but if you're using {filter:} by itself in a stylesheet, that's not a polyfill, thats valid ie css. just a small difference.

Comment: <shrug> it provides functionality that the browser doesn't provide natively (in this case CSS3 box shadows). That is the definition of a poly-fill.

Comment: the browser does provide it natively. its using IE's native styles to accomplish the desired effect. view your PIE source files yo.

Comment: It's not providing CSS3 box shadows natively. If it was, CSS3 syntax would be accomplishing the effect.

Comment: you're right, it's providing css2.1 box shadows. cause ie5 could do it 10 years ago. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

`-moz-box-shadow` only works in FF and Chrome. In Internet Explorer you have to use `box-shadow`.

They can be used together:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
box-shadow: 0 0 20x #000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use --ms-box-shadow,
or try just using just plain box-shadow.

Also, it will only work in IE v9

Answer (score -1):

Thats CSS3, which is not supported in any IE browser under 9, because IE is traditionally a substandard browser. So unless you are in IE9, or 10 (somehow), you are out of luck

Comment: As shown by other respondents, there are ways to get it to work in IE lt 9.

Comment: Ok why did you downvte mine, like 5 other people said the same thing